# Expo + React Native + Self Hosted OTA not working

Tags: android, react-native, expo, ota

I am trying to host OTA on my own server. I followed the [Hosting Updates on Your Servers](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/hosting-your-app/) guide but with no luck.

To dig deeper I called the method `Updates.checkForUpdateAsync()` and logged the error message.

```
Error Code: ERR_UPDATES_CHECK
Error Message: Failed to parse manifest data
```

However, I checked the manifest URL and got the JSON response.

```
{
  "name": "local-update",
  "slug": "local-update",
  "version": "1.0.13",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
    "imageUrl": "https://username.github.io/expo-local-update/assets/4dc203c1f48ad8b1e9734613e88be661"
  },
  "updates": {
    "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
    "url": "https://username.github.io/expo-local-update"
  },
  "ios": {
    "supportsTablet": true
  },
  "android": {
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "foregroundImageUrl": "https://username.github.io/expo-local-update/assets/97dae5a0e62ad8551d8a31897b425e63"
    },
    "package": "com.jazasoft.localupdate"
  },
  "web": {
    "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
  },
  "sdkVersion": "44.0.0",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android",
    "web"
  ],
  "currentFullName": "@expouser/local-update",
  "originalFullName": "@expouser/local-update",
  "locales": {},
  "iconUrl": "https://username.github.io/expo-local-update/assets/4e3f888fc8475f69fd5fa32f1ad5216a",
  "bundledAssets": [],
  "assetUrlOverride": "./assets",
  "publishedTime": "2022-02-04T07:29:17.098Z",
  "commitTime": "2022-02-04T07:29:17.098Z",
  "releaseId": "aa1838e5-dae6-4162-8929-31880b321456",
  "revisionId": "XbAJ1eBGvo",
  "id": "@expouser/local-update",
  "platform": "android",
  "bundleUrl": "https://username.github.io/expo-local-update/bundles/android-e151ab3dba93758ccd28a2709f4b4f49.js",
  "dependencies": [
    "expo",
    "expo-application",
    "expo-status-bar",
    "expo-updates",
    "react",
    "react-dom",
    "react-native",
    "react-native-web"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue!